# Best Practice for Split Domain Routing - Exchange Server

Tags: exchange, domain, email-server, mx-record

We have a hosted Exchange environment and would like to get a mirrored copy of all of our accounts in real time. Would Split Domain Routing allow us to route emails from the same accounts to 2 different exchange servers using the same domain?

- Server [A] at Main Office running exchange and tied to MyDomain.com
- Server [B] at Remote Office running exchange and will be tied to MyDomain.com

We control the DNS records & Server [B]. We have no control over Server [A].

A basic backup all the PSTs and migrate is the obvious plan but we don't know when we will be losing the Server [A] and leaving early puts us out of compliance with regulators.

Is there a way to route all emails to [A] uninterrupted but at the same time route all emails to [B] as a 'backup' that we could use for future migration away from [A]?

Comment: When you say this is hosted what do you mean? Hosted by an external host/provider?

Comment: You can migrate mailboxes from one Exchange server to another (including over a WAN) without having previously set up replicas of the data. There's no need to do this for migration purposes. If you are trying to have secondary storage of all the mailbox data for use in case of a failure, you should look into creating a Database Availability Group, which is supported over WAN links.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: A DAG is what I was going to suggest as well, but I think the OP may be referring to Exchange being hosted by an external/third party.

Comment: @joeqwerty Good point. I would say the notion of "this isn't a good way to prepare for a migration" stands either way. There does seem to be a minimal downtime method for migrating from one forest/org to another: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17854.moving-mailboxes-between-exchange-organizations.aspx The downtime for each user would begin when the migration batch is completed and the downtime ends when the user's client(s) are reconfigured to connect to the new forest/org.

Comment: Yes external provider that we don't control. We do control the domain and the DNS records. DAG would be great but I don't have control of the host. Agreed on not a good way to prepare for a migration - as it stands the parent organization controls the existing forest and we would be disbanding from them. Essentially trying to maintain control of our data and minimize the downtime without letting them know we are leaving until we know we have a backup serve ready.

Comment: How many mailboxes are we talking about? With so little control, I'm assuming it's a small number. If it's under 30 mailboxes or so your best bet might be to plan for a weekend of downtime and just export all the mailboxes to PSTs so they can be imported. Without any ability to establish trust relationships, etc., PST export is the only 100% reliable way I can think of to keep all of your mailbox data. I suggest you edit the limitations into the question and spell out exactly what you control and what you don't so you can get effective answers.

Comment: yes under 50 mailboxes - the timing is the issue. PST backup it the way I have recommended but we can't jump ship early due to regulators and our existing relationship. A complicated mess.

Comment: It might be wise to do a mast PST export anyway so at least you have a point in time snapshot so if things really go bad and they try to disconnect you from your mail, you have history to work from while you try to get set up again.

Comment: that's a good point - snap shot the entire mess in case it goes south, thanks.